# How do I switch/select types during compile-time?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compile-time, type-traits

Is there a standard way for me to select a type at **compile-time** on an unsigned index in c++11?

For example, something like:

```
using type_0 = static_switch<0, T, U>;  // yields type T
using type_1 = static_switch<1, T, U>;  // yields type U
```

If there is a variadic-template version, it would be very useful.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This should work:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename... T>
using static_switch = typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<T...> >::type;
```

Another method:

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct static_switch {
    using type = typename static_switch<N - 1, Ts...>::type;
};
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct static_switch<0, T, Ts...> {
    using type = T;
};
```

Comment: +1 Outstanding answer. I'm always interested in new ways to use variadic templates. Thanks for another one.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain not all compilers support it (it they do, it is their latest versions)

Comment: @BЈовић Thanks; I have access to a few different compilers at work, but unfortunately, none of them support C++11 to even start testing this!

Comment: Note that something like `std::tuple<void>` yields an invalid instantiation. Someone optimistic will point out that since the only requirement on `std::tuple_element` is that the index be correct, then something like `std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<void>>::type` should not instantiate `std::tuple<void>` and thus should be well-formed on all implementations. Someone less so optimistic might feel inclined to implement a good old type-list to avoid the consideration altogether.

Answer (score 10):

You could probably use a `boost::mpl::vector` to store your types and use `boost::mpl::at<v, n>::type` to get a type with from the index.

```
template<std::size_t N, typename... T>
using static_switch = typename boost::mpl::at<boost::mpl::vector<T...>, N>::type;
```

Answer (score 9):

How about

```
 template<size_t N, typename T, typename U>
 struct static_switch {};

 template<typename T, typename U>
 struct static_switch<0, T, U>{typedef T type;};

 template<typename T, typename U>
 struct static_switch<1, T, U>{typedef U type;};
```

You would use it as follows:

```
using type_0 = static_switch<0, T, U>::type;  // yields type T
using type_1 = static_switch<1, T, U>::type;  // yields type U
```

This is more or less implemented for you in [std::conditional](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

Comment: Note: `std::conditional` is great if there are only 2 alternatives. Since the OP is talking about an index, there might be more.

Answer (score 2):

With C++17 you can also go about this another way. Instead of calculating the type explicitly you can use `constexpr if` and do different things (including returning different types) directly:

```
template<size_t N>
decltype(auto) foo() {
    if constexpr(N % 2 == 0) {
        return std::string("Hello I'm even");
    } else {
        return std::pair(
             std::vector<char>{ 'O', 'd', 'd', ' ', 'v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e' },
             [](){ return N; });         
  }
}

foo<0>()           // "Hello I'm even"
foo<21>().second() // 21
```

You can also use this to get just the type:

```
using type_0 = decltype(foo<0>());
using type_1 = decltype(foo<1>());
```